# adding white border along a circle UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have generated a circle UIImage using a mask as following (where masked_circle is a black circle):

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    UIImage *maskImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"masked_circle.png"];
    CGImageRef maskImageRef = [maskImage CGImage];

    // create a bitmap graphics context the size of the image
    CGContextRef mainViewContentContext = CGBitmapContextCreate (NULL, maskImage.size.width, maskImage.size.height, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    CGFloat ratio = 0;
    ratio = maskImage.size.width/ self.image_.size.width;

    if(ratio * self.image_.size.height < maskImage.size.height) {
        ratio = maskImage.size.height/ self.image_.size.height;
    }

    CGRect rect1  = {{0, 0}, {maskImage.size.width, maskImage.size.height}};
    CGRect rect2  = {{-((self.image_.size.width*ratio)-maskImage.size.width)/2 , -((self.image_.size.height*ratio)-maskImage.size.height)/2}, {self.image_.size.width*ratio, self.image_.size.height*ratio}};

    CGContextClipToMask(mainViewContentContext, rect1, maskImageRef);
    CGContextDrawImage(mainViewContentContext, rect2, self.image_.CGImage);

    CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(mainViewContentContext);
    CGContextRelease(mainViewContentContext);

    UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage];
```

Now after this I wanted to add a 1px white border around the circle image, how can I do so?

Comment: Will the UIImage be in a UIImageView or are you wanting to draw the actual border in the UIImage?

Comment: wanted to draw the actual border in the UIImage itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code that draws a border around a frame with a corner radius.  Make that radius equal to half size and you've got a circle!

```
CGFloat strokeWidth =1.0;
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, strokeWidth);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor grayColor].CGColor);

CGFloat radius = 7.0;
CGRect rrect = self.bounds;
rrect.size.width = rrect.size.width - strokeWidth*2;
rrect.size.height = rrect.size.height - strokeWidth*2;
rrect.origin.x = rrect.origin.x + (strokeWidth / 2);
rrect.origin.y = rrect.origin.y + (strokeWidth / 2);
CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(rrect);
CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(rrect);

if (radius > width/2.0)
    radius = width/2.0;
if (radius > height/2.0)
    radius = height/2.0;   

CGFloat minx = CGRectGetMinX(rrect);
CGFloat midx = CGRectGetMidX(rrect);
CGFloat maxx = CGRectGetMaxX(rrect);
CGFloat miny = CGRectGetMinY(rrect);
CGFloat midy = CGRectGetMidY(rrect);
CGFloat maxy = CGRectGetMaxY(rrect);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, minx, midy);
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, minx, miny, midx, miny, radius);
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, maxx, miny, maxx, midy, radius);
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, maxx, maxy, midx, maxy, radius);
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, minx, maxy, minx, midy, radius);
CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a much simpler solution to turn any view, but specifically a UIImageView into a circle with a border of varying size and color.  This of course assumes you're dealing with a square image like an icon.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView (Shapes)
- (void)makeCircle;
- (void)makeCircleWithBorderColor:(UIColor *) color Width:(CGFloat) width;
@end


@implementation UIView (Shapes)

- (void)makeCircle {
    CALayer *lyr = self.layer;
    lyr.masksToBounds = YES;
    lyr.cornerRadius = self.bounds.size.width / 2; // assumes image is a square
}

- (void)makeCircleWithBorderColor:(UIColor *) color Width:(CGFloat) width {
    [self makeCircle];
    CALayer *lyr = self.layer;
    lyr.borderWidth = width;
    lyr.borderColor = [color CGColor];
}
@end
```

Comment: Not necessary to create *lyr you can work directly with self.layer ,+1 for simplicity.